# Is there a Rust function which counts frequencies in a Vec?

Tags: vector, rust

I want to count the frequencies of all elements in a given `Vec`, e.g. something like

```
count_frequencies(vec![1,1,1,4,1,2,3,5,4])
```

should return the following `Vec`:

```
[(1,4), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,1)]
```

(the order does not matter). While I know how I could implement such a function, it seems to me like there should already be an existing implementation in some crate. After some googling, I only found a crate named [`frequency`](https://docs.rs/frequency/1.0.1/frequency/), but didn't find any example in the documentation.

So, my question is: is there a crate that can achieve this task and, if so, how can I use it?

Edit: If you as well know a function which goes in the other direction, I would also be interested in that :)

Comment: this kind of thing is easily implemented using a hashmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itertools offers [`counts`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.counts), but you'd have to convert the result (a `HashMap`) into a `Vec` yourself.

Alternatively, sort the vector (costs O(n log n), but may - in practice - be faster than a HashMap-based approach) and use [`dedup_with_count`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.dedup_with_count) on the sorted vector.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't really needed because it is one-liner anyway:

```rust
    let frequencies = v
          .iter()
          .copied()
          .fold(HashMap::new(), |mut map, val|{
              map.entry(val)
                 .and_modify(|frq|*frq+=1)
                 .or_insert(1);
              map
          });
```

There are different requirements for different tasks so there is no need to make some standard method for this.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer `*map.entry(val).or_default() += 1`.  And if the results are required to be sorted, a `BTreeMap` over a `HashMap` (although, depending on what is known about the possible input values, some other data structure could also be more appropriate).

Comment: @eggyal You show that there is a lot of different requirements for such task so there is no need to make standard method for this.

Comment: That's an awful lot of lines for a one-liner